# How to calculate the virtual bytes of a process

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

I tried to calculate the virtual bytes using below formula:-
virtual bytes=working set + private bytes + standby list
but I am not sure how to we find "standby list"

I want to know how do we calculate the virtual bytes of a process?